# Details on Android OS massive data usage

Tags: nexus-5, system, data-monitoring

Yesterday Android OS on my Nexus 5 transferred 44,7 GB (!) data over both WiFi (42,2 GB) and mobile data (2,5 GB). I have no idea why the data transfer started, and I have no idea why it stopped after one day, and I have no idea what data was transferred, and to/from where.

I haven't changed or installed anything on the phone.

Is it possible to see exactly what data has been exchanged by the Android OS and why?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can - details here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/why-you-dont-need-third-party-apps-to-manage-background-data-use-in-android-jelly-bean/

From the article:

> "To access the Data Usage screen, open your Android phone’s Settings
>   screen, and tap Data usage under Wireless & Networks. You’ll see a
>   graph displaying how much mobile data all apps on your phone used over
>   a period of time. Specify the “Data usage cycle”  time period that
>   your carrier uses to determine your monthly data usage and you should
>   see the amount of data you’ve used in the past billing cycle."

Hope it helps!

Comment: He was talking not about general Android data usage but "Android OS" process data usage